# What is the last VLC Media Player version for Windows 98/98SE/ME?

Tags: windows-98, windows-me

What is the last VLC Media Player version for Windows 98/98SE/ME ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Not requiring [unicows.dll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode), the last version for Windows 98/98SE/ME is 0.8.4a (13/12/2005; slighly newer than 0.8.4)
- Requiring [unicows.dll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode), the last version officially supported on Windows 98/ME is 0.8.6i (14 August 2008).
- With KernelEx you can install up to version 3.0.8 (20 August 2019).

References:

- [VLC Media Player - KernelEx Wiki](http://kernelex.sourceforge.net/wiki/VLC_Media_Player)